# Loading thumbnail image in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, thumbnails

I have a `UITableView` within a `UIViewController` and I'm trying to load the imageFile as a thumbnail in my `UITableViewCell`.  All `UITableViewCell` data is being loaded from parse and i can successfully load the `NSObject` name and username into the `UITableViewCell` but for some reason im getting an error with the thumbnial image.  my code is as follows (for cell).

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.groups.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
PFObject *group = [self.groups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

PFFile *thumbnail = [group objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width/2;
thumbnailImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cc"];
thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
[thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
nameLabel.text = [group objectForKey:@"name"];
UILabel *usernameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
usernameLabel.text = [group objectForKey:@"creatorName"];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is the error? Aren't you getting any image at all?

Comment: the app crashes with this error " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78fc77a0' " and highlights "thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;" green with a thread 1:signal SIGABRT

Comment: as well as this in my log " -[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78fc77a0 "

Comment: thumbnail is PFFile . IT is not a PFObject

Comment: you need to assign a PFobject to thumbnailImageView.file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `[cell viewWithTag:100]` is a UIImageView in storyboard. Try to set the UIImageView class to PFImageView in identity inspector, hope this would solved your problem too.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning object to PFFile:

The correct usage of PFFile is:

```
PFFile *thumbnail = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData];
```

The correct usage of PFObject is:

```
 PFObject *group = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"your class name"];
```